# Some files gets huge online

Tags: file, size

I have a file, for example

**admin.css**

Which is **4 KB**

But when I upload it to the server of mine, it gets heavy.

It's header is **405 MB**, and it's body is **270 MB**

Why is it this way?

My site is pretty slow.

---

Look at here, **admin.css** and **custom_toaster.css** are **548 MB** & **1015 MB**

(Even though on my pc theyre only **several KB's**)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using "bundles", which packages website resources such as jquery and bootstrap.  Browsers will only upload a bundle when it changes.